# Duplicating the same plot in Python in one figure with separate legends

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I wanted to duplicate the same plot on the same figure with different colors and legends and here is my minimalistic working code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_layout(data):
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    p, = ax.plot(data,'o')

    p.set_markerfacecolor('g')
    # Presumably lots of complicated settings here

    return fig, ax, p

data = data = np.linspace(0,1)

f1, a1, p1 = make_layout(data)
f2, a2, p2 = make_layout(data**2)


p2.set_markerfacecolor('yellow')
```

Here are the two plots i got in separate figures and they don't look like the same. How can i do that? Thank you for any help.

[image]

[image]

I wanted to merge them in one same figure. I also wanted to add legends and labels.

Comment: pass your Axes object as a parameter to the plotting function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plotting function needs to accept an Axes object as a parameter. You then create the figure and axes outside of the function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_layout(data, ax):
    p, = ax.plot(data, 'o')
    p.set_markerfacecolor('g')
    return p
```

So to plot everything on 1 Axes, you'd do:

```
data = data = np.linspace(0,1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
p1 = make_layout(data, ax)
p2 = make_layout(data**2, ax)
p2.set_markerfacecolor('yellow')
```

If you want separate axes, you'd do something like this:

```
data = data = np.linspace(0,1)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
p1 = make_layout(data, ax1)
p2 = make_layout(data**2, ax2)
p2.set_markerfacecolor('yellow')
```

Comment: That's the answer i was looking for and thank you so much, plotting everything on 1 axes is what i wanted. How about if we have to add two legends for the plots and plot in lines instead of circles. I tried `p, = ax.plot(data, 'b-')` but it is making all the plots in blue line.

Comment: @user2154227 https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#controlling-line-properties